# How to use clearInterval() to stop a loop in a discord bot

Tags: javascript, loops, bots, discord, discord.js

So i wanted a command that spammed someone in dms and a command that stops the spam

I got it to here but whenever I use 'dm stop' instead of just stopping the command it crashes the whole bot

```
bot.on('message', message=>{

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){


    case 'dm':
            if(args[1] === 'spam'){
                const userdm = message.mentions.users.first()
                let dmloop = setInterval(function(){ userdm.send('Hoi'); }, 1)
            }        
            if(args[1] === 'stop'){
                clearInterval(dmloop)

            }else{
                message.channel.send('What do you want me to do with dms?');
                }
        break;

})

bot.login(token);
```

In the terminal it says that "dmloop" in clearInterval(dmloop)is not defined

Comment: API abuse warning. "You shall not ... use the API or SDK in connection with any Applications that include any malware or other harmful code or that **facilitate spamming in any way**..." ([Developer Terms of Service](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/legal), provision 2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to take your interval variable `dmloop` out of the ifs, like this:

```js
let dmloop = null;
bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'dm':
        if (args[1] === 'spam') {
            const userdm = message.mentions.users.first();
            if(dmloop==null){
                dmloop = setInterval(function() {
                    userdm.send('Hoi');
                }, 1);}
            }
        }
        if (args[1] === 'stop') {
            clearInterval(dmloop);
            dmloop = null;
        } else {
            message.channel.send('What do you want me to do with dms?');
        }
        break;
    })//...
```

Comment: Ok i tried this and it no longer crashes the bot but "dm stop" just doesnt do anything and it spams forever

Comment: Added an if to check if the variable is initialized so it doesnt initialize it again, and also a set to null to initialize it when the stop is called.

Comment: Ok so i tried this and when i did '-dm' it would spam the reponse into the chat until i turned the bot off and when i did the spam command it would spam the dm channel and the response in the server channel "-dm stop" didnt do anything either time i also had to move
                dmloop = null;
over
                clearInterval(dmloop);